# number? can't be used in spec

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

In Clojure 1.9.0-alpha13, I can define a spec predicate using `spec/and` and `integer?` but not `and` and `number?`, it appears.  This is puzzling.  It's also puzzling that there is no error when I define the predicate, but only when I try to define a spec using it.

```
user=> (use '[clojure.spec :as s])
...
nil
user=> (s/def pos-int? (s/and integer? pos?))
user/pos-int?
user=> (s/def ::foo pos-int?)
:user/foo
user=> (s/def pos-num? (s/and number? pos?))
user/pos-num?
user=> (s/def ::bar pos-num?)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: pos-num? ...
```

Why do I get an error in the second case, but not the first?  Is this a feature involving a distinction that I'm unaware of, or a bug?

Note that there is no error if I define `::bar` directly:

```
user=> (s/def ::bar (s/and number? pos?))
:user/bar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code here is incorrect. `s/def` should be called with a qualified-keyword to register a spec, not a symbol.

So this:

```
user=> (s/def pos-int? (s/and integer? pos?))
user/pos-int?
```

is not doing what you think it is. It is actually registering a function definition (which you typically do via `s/fdef`) under the symbol `user/pos-int?`.

```
user=> (s/def ::foo pos-int?)
:user/foo
```

This works because `pos-int?` is an existing function in clojure.core (that is, it's not using your prior definition at all).

This also appears to work but is similarly incorrect:

```
user=> (s/def pos-num? (s/and number? pos?))
user/pos-num?
```

This fails:

```
user=> (s/def ::bar pos-num?)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: pos-num? ...
```

because pos-num is *not* an existing predicate.

Presuming you want to register two specs for positive integers and numbers you could do:

```
(s/def ::pos-int (s/and integer? pos?))
(s/def ::pos-num (s/and number? pos?))
```

Comment: Ah, thanks very much for clearing up my multi-faceted confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your have discovered an interaction with the pre-defined `pos-int?` from `clojure.core`.  In the source code:

src/clj/clojure/core.clj   line 1400

```
(defn pos-int?
  "Return true if x is a positive fixed precision integer"
  {:added "1.9"}
  [x] (and (int? x)
           (pos? x)))
```

There is no `pos-num?` present.

Comment: Also, you may wish to post this question to the Clojure google group email list to get a more through explanation.